# Can I use up all IPv4 IP addresses using public cloud?

Tags: cloud

On public clouds like AWS and Azure, each account/subscription can create a certain amount of public IPs.

I wonder if I can use up all IPv4 IP addresses by creating a huge amount of accounts/subscriptions, given that I do pay for that.

Comment: In theory, you can keep creating new accounts and keep buying all unallocated IP addresses, Microsoft/Amazon will just keep having to search for new block once the ones they have runs out, until all blocks that have unused addresses runs out. In practice, they'll be forced to jack up the price every time it becomes signficantly more difficult to find new unused IP address block. So you'll likely go bankrupt before you can grab everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans-Martin has answered, you can't use up all the IPv4 addresses in the world as you can only use up Microsoft or AWS's allocation.

However, you're not actually going to be able to do that. You can probably create a few accounts and nothing will happen, but before you get to the sort of number that would make any difference to a big cloud provider, one of their monitoring systems will note the large number of accounts being created with the same credit card (or the same small number of credit cards) and they'll rapidly shut down *all* the accounts and blacklist you.

Answer (score 1):

No. Microsoft and Amazon (like every other provider) have limited sets of IP addresses assigned to them, they can only assign those to their customers.